# Candlestick charts in python.. Despite all examples found - cannot fix the blank dates for weekends/holidays

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, candlestick-chart

I did research the issue and found some examples of how other users fixed the issue with gaps on the chart for the weekends/holidays, but, i am just unable to fix my code to resolve the issue.

i download the data from bloomberg api, i can chart it, but i am unable to fix the chart to look like the examples that i found.

i did find 2-3 of other possible solutions on how to resolve the issue, but i dont knot what i am doing wrong that it is not resolving the issue.

```
 # bloomberg download code here no need to bore you with something you wont be able to run without a terminal.. sorry...

 adjclosevalues = pd.DataFrame(adj_values,columns = smartindex)
 adjclosevalues=adjclosevalues.set_index('Date', drop=True)


 adjclosevalues = adjclosevalues.reset_index()
 adjclosevalues.Date = pd.to_datetime(adjclosevalues.Date)
 adjclosevalues = adjclosevalues[['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']]
 adjclosevalues["Date"] = 
 adjclosevalues["Date"].apply(mdates.date2num)

 fig = plt.figure()
 ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0), colspan=20)
 candlestick_ohlc(ax1, adjclosevalues.values, width=0.4, colorup='#77d879', colordown='#db3f3f')

 for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(90)

    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(10))
    ax1.grid(True)

    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Price')
    plt.title('Chart')
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.09, bottom=0.20, right=0.94, top=0.90, wspace=0.2, hspace=0)
    plt.show(block=False)
```

I know it is probably something very simple, but just i cannot figure out how to adjust the index to display just the business days AND make it work.  I did go through other examples. it should be embarrassing and it is.

Comment: Maybe try https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html  and use 'B' for frequency?